# How to build a full text search similar (as quick & as accurate) to Google Drive?

Tags: java, database, google-app-engine, full-text-search

Google Drive searching is really amazing.
It built up a full text search index instantly right after I had uploaded the document(pdf/M$ office document).

Since I want to use this technology in my own GAE project,I was wondering

1.is there any existing api from(Google/others) provide this function

2.how to implement by myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On App Engine you can use [Search API](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/search/overview), to do full-test indexing & querying.

Comment: Search api will NOT index the docs (pdf word etc) automatically . You have to know how to read them and manually create the index of texts. Even if you do all that and have libs to read every propietary format it will still not be like drive as it doesnt  find subtexts (only variations using the ~ operator)

Answer (score -2):

You can use following options.

Google desktop and not sure about api.

IIS index server thenyou can do query it index files too.

Dtseach is tool with api but paid.

Apache api i forgot name but will post it shortly.